# На сайте вк формы для теста загрузки фото. ответ от photos.getWallUploadServer , что копировать в photos.saveWallPhoto

Tags: vkontakte-api

Выполняю тут: `https://vk.com/dev/photos.getWallUploadServer?params[group_id]=14354205&params[v]=3.0`
приходит такой ответ :

```
    {"server":841238,"photo":
    "[{\"photo\":\"a660539ecc:x\",\"sizes\":
    [[\"s\",\"841238205\",\"35b\",\"GINu11q2nMI\",75,55], 
    [\"m\",\"841238205\",\"35c\",\"l_h1PiJpKBQ\",130,96], 
    [\"x\",\"841238205\",\"35d\",\"S--022k_2JM\",350,259], 
    [\"o\",\"841238205\",\"35e\",\"cbSMcgnE0Yo\",130,96],
    [\"p\",\"841238205\",\"35f\",\"nnmUSZ7ZPKg\",200,148],
    [\"q\",\"841238205\",\"360\",\"TinpBdp06E8\",320,237],
    [\"r\",\"841238205\",\"361\",\"qASQVUHeDio\",350,259]],
    \"kid\":\"67ff16c39b6631b6c30030d86c000000\",\"debug\":\"xsxmxxxoxpxqxrx\"}]","hash":"cb736c966c38308978e3f5a6780e2131"}
```

тут `https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto?params[v]=5.65` вставляю **сервер**:841238 **фото**:

```
[{\"photo\":\"a660539ecc:x\",\"sizes\":
[[\"s\",\"841238205\",\"35b\",\"GINu11q2nMI\",75,55],
[\"m\",\"841238205\",\"35c\",\"l_h1PiJpKBQ\",130,96],
[\"x\",\"841238205\",\"35d\",\"S--022k_2JM\",350,259],
[\"o\",\"841238205\",\"35e\",\"cbSMcgnE0Yo\",130,96],
[\"p\",\"841238205\",\"35f\",\"nnmUSZ7ZPKg\",200,148],
[\"q\",\"841238205\",\"360\",\"TinpBdp06E8\",320,237],
[\"r\",\"841238205\",\"361\",\"qASQVUHeDio\",350,259]],
\"kid\":\"67ff16c39b6631b6c30030d86c000000\",\"debug\":\"xsxmxxxoxpxqxrx\"}]
```

**Хэш**: `cb736c966c38308978e3f5a6780e2131`
Ошибка:

> One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photos_list is
>   invalid .

Пробовал в Фото убрать все слэши. тогда пишет что Хэш неправильный. Фото PNG гружу, размер небольшой. Может я где лишние скобки квадратные взял или кавычки нужны? я уже по всякому попробовал . никак. Мне нужно понять что копировать, чтобы на java это всё написать под андроид.

Comment: Просто распарсите как JSON и передайте все нужные поля как JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я правильно делал, что убирал экранирование и все поля тоже верно определил. Проблема была в том, что при вызове метода photos.`getWallUploadServer` мы должны передать `group_id` . Если нужно на стену себе , то нужно id пользователя сюда писать. Если в группу то и id группы. Нету такого, что есть два поля `group_id` и `user_id` из которых надо заполнить лишь одно. А при выполнении следующего метода `photos.saveWallPhoto` , если мы публикуем себе на стену то `group_id` мы должны писать и в поле `group_id` и в `user_id` , т.е. одно и тоже значение. Иначе вернет инвалид хэш.